# How to find a list of entries where they have the same id and certain part numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table which has three columns: id, layer and part_number.

The table looks like this:

[image: Table Snippet]

I'd like to find the id that has part_numbers: 412789, 412801 & 412806. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `record_id`, and do an "IN" statement, to grab all ID's with those part numbers, and then fetch all the unique record_id's with any of those part numbers. In this case, it would be `1`:

```
SELECT record_id
FROM parts_table
WHERE part_number IN (412789, 412789, 412806)
GROUP BY record_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct:

```
SELECT distinct record_id
FROM parts_table
WHERE part_number IN (412789, 412789, 412806)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the image of your table, but something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT id
FROM (
  SELECT id, part_number
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE part_number IN (142789, 412801, 412806) -- Restrict part numbers
  GROUP BY id, part_number -- Get one row per id / part_number
) src
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 -- Only return id's with three rows (one for each part_number)
GROUP BY id
```

Give it a try and let me know.

**Update**
To support variable `part_numbers`, you should parameterize the query using a stored procedure.  Here are some links to get you started:

[Stored Procedures - Intro](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)
[Stored Procedures - Parameters](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx)
[Stored Procedures - More](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-procedure.php)

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I'm not sure if I explained it clearly enough so I'll try again... What I would like is the id where a row exists for all three of the part numbers. If possible this has to work for more than three part numbers, so say there were 4 then it would search for an id that has a record for all four of the part numbers.

Comment: If the `part_number` values are variable and not hard-coded, then how are you passing that information into your query?  If you want to handle a case of variable `part_numbers`, you'd need to parameterize the query using a function / stored procedure.  You can pass in the `part_number` values as an array.

Comment: Would you be able to show me this?

Comment: Sorry, I have to run for now...but I will post a few links above to get started.  It's not too complicated to parameterize the query, so give it a shot.  The only potentially tricky part would be handling an array as the input parameter (not sure the best way to do that in MySql).  You'd also need to calculate the # items in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to return here is all the records from your table, where the record_id is shared across the 3 part_numbers.
It's a little messy, however, you should be able to do this with the following SQL:

```
with cte as 
(select record_id,count(*) cnt 
from parts_table 
where part_number in (412789,412801,412806)
group by record_id having count(*) =3
)
select * from parts_table p
join cte c on c.record_id=p.record_id
where p.part_number in (412789,412801,412806)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your query, I think you've got the idea but it didn't work on my machine. I haven't been using SQL for long so it could just be that I'm doing something wrong. I'm using mySql if that helps at all :)

Comment: How about trying the following?  select * from parts_table 
where record_id in (select record_id from parts_table where part_number in (412789,412801,412806) group by record_id having count(*) =3 ) and part_number in (412789,412801,412806)